# json condition with <null>

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to check if Color is "" I want to print "default" it's not taking nil as null and not taking NSnull with any in condition check

I have json :

```
variant = (
            {
            Color = "<null>";
            Occasion = "<null>";
            Size = "<null>";
          }
);
```

---

My code

```
var StrColor = String()

let Color = (self.Str.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Color")
print(Color)
if Color == nil
{
    self.StrColor = "null"
}
else
{
    self.StrColor = (self.Str.object(at: 0) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Color") as! String
}
```

but it's not taking nil as "" now how to correct it.

Comment: I think you could use 'Color.isEmpty' to check if color is ""?

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let variant = self.str.first as? [String:Any],
   if  variant["tbl_sub_category_details"] as? NSNull  != nil {
        print("Value is null")
   }else {
        print("value is not null")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `<null>` is `NSNull` which is **not** equal to `nil`.

The easiest way is to check if the value is a `String` as you need to unwrap the optional anyway.

This code uses native Swift collection types and key subscription, you are strongly discouraged from casting to `AnyObject` and using `valueForKey` in Swift:

```
if let variant = self.str.first as? [String:Any],
   let color = variant["Color"] as? String {
    // value is String
} else {
    // value is NSNull
}
```

And please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.